# Passing method to lodash with vue gives 'Expected a function'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, vuejs2

I am trying to pass a Vue function to the lodash throttle method. Shouldn't I just be able to do something like this?

When I am trying to do this I am getting the following error:

> Error in callback for watcher "query": "TypeError: Expected a function"

Watcher

```
watch: {
    query() {
        throttle(this.autocomplete(), 400);
    }
}
```

Methods

```
methods: {
    autocomplete() {}
}
```

Even though I am passing a function reference I am still getting an error message. If I wrap it with a anonymous function it won't fire:

```
throttle(() => { this.autocomplete(); }, 400);
```

I just checked and the `autocomplete` function does actually seem to fire regardless of the error that it is not a function in my example at the top.

What is going wrong here?

**Edit:**

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2780/

Comment: As @str said, `this.autocomplete` will return `undefined`. To get reference you can do `this.$options.methods.autocomplete`. not sure if its recommended. but even after doing that, it did not call `autocomplete` method.  even after passing a function, throttle did not work. see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2783/). There is also alternate solution in the fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the return value of `this.autocomplete()` (maybe `undefined`) and not the function reference. If you want to do the latter, you have to omit the brackets:

```
watch: {
    query() {
        throttle(this.autocomplete, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but nothing happens at all, my autcomplete won't fire. Not even something like a `console.log`.

Comment: @Stephan-v Maybe you should add more code. What is `throttle`?

Comment: Throttle is the lodash function which I imported: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle

Comment: This is creating a throttled function every time query changes. You want to constantly call the *same* throttled function like the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Working approach:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    query: ''
  },
  watch: {
    query: function() {
      this.autocomplete()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    autocomplete: _.throttle(function() {
      console.log('test');
    }, 50)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>

<div id="demo" v-cloak>
    <input type="text" v-model="query">
</div>
```

As @Bill Criswell commented,

> This is creating a throttled function every time query changes. You
>   want to constantly call the same throttled function like the answer
>   below.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you need to define the throttled function with a non-invoked callback in a variable, and then invoke that as a function:

```js
var throttled = throttle(this.autocomplete, 400)
watch: {
    query() {
        throttled();
    }
}
```

Just spent quite awhile trying to figure that one out...